# How do I open local .msg files in web browser (html format) and display embedded pictures

Tags: html, vb.net, outlook, msg

I know how to open local .msg files in webbrowser in html format.

The problem is when the .msg has embedded pictures, the only thing that appears is a blank space ("picture not found") where it is supposed to be.

If I open the .msg file in Outlook, I see the images correctly, but in my program I can't see embedded pictures.

I'm using Vb .Net and I'm very newbie.

Comment: Are you following [this example which exports the HTML Body](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/openinbrowser.htm)? If so - share with us (*via [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar*) the exported HTML from Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Save the message in the MHTML format - it embeds the pictures.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. If it's the only solution, that's not good for me. I need to deal with .msg files.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded images are attachments. Use some API able to read .msg file format and get attachments and insert/link in the html body

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271261/how-to-create-an-outlook-msg-file-from-a-web-service